# Who is responsible for deleting the PostImages? The PostsController or the PostImagesController?

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, controller

This question is about a concept in MVC:

Supposing I have two basics entities in my system: the `Post` that has many `PostImage` (a 1:N relation).

At certain moment, I'm editing a `Post` and I want to delete some `PostImage`.

Here is my doubt: which `Controller` is responsible for performing the action to delete the `PostImage`?

a) The `PostsController` (the `PostImage` only exists inside the `Post`) ?
b) The `PostsImageController`?
c) Both are correct choices.

*Note: I'm using CakePHP, but I think this is irrelevant because MVC is a concept, right?*

Comment: Actually, if you are using CakePHP, you should not care about MVC, because said framework does not implement anything even remotely resembling MVC design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PostImagesController` is the one responsible for telling the `PostImageModel` to delete a record.

What you can do inside the `PostsController` is call the `delete()` method from the `PostImage` model, assuming you've related them correctly.

```
$this->Post->PostImage->delete($postImageId);
```